# Data not getting saved to database from the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Class UserController has the following code:

```
 def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user].permit(:userid,:password,:email))
      render plain: params[:user].inspect+"||"+@user.inspect
      #@user.save
      #flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      #redirect_to @user
  end
```

The form has following code: (`@user` or `:user`, doesn't matter, output is same)

```
<%= form_for :user, url:users_path do |f| %>
<%= f.label:USERID %><%= f.text_field :userid %><br />
<%= f.label:PASSWORD %><%= f.password_field :password %><br />
<%= f.label:EMAIL %><%= f.text_field :email %><br />
<br />
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I fill the form, I get this output:

```
{"userid"=>"viky", "password"=>"123456", "email"=>"aa"}||#<User id: nil, userid: nil, password: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As you can see, the userid , password and email are getting passed in the params but not appearing in @users, I don't know why.
And then if I type @users.save then it saves a null row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess your permit syntax is wrong

Use : `params.require(:user).permit(:userid,:password,:email)`

Comment: @user1735921 I updated answer , can you check again ?

Answer (score 0):

it was because of attr_accessor in user model, I removed the attr_accessors from user model and it worked fine